# unable to align views horizontally in linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, alignment

I'm trying to horizontally place views inside a linear layout such that I can align these views horizontally but not next to each other. I tried giving margin,padding values etc. but nothing worked for me. All the views remain placed next to each other.

I want the digital clock in the extreme right and the WiFi image in the center. 
Please suggest what should I use to align views with separation within them using minimum hard code.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_bar_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signal_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/signal1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nosim_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/wifi1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/battery1"
        />

    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digClock_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align things more `Relatively`, so that something is always at the left edge, and so on, you should use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). It gives you more flexibility to work on things like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Relative Layout. Its much more easier to make layouts with that. In your case they remain next to each, because I guess you have set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` try changing it to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and try.